# Left join with Where in Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to write this SQL query with Eloquent ORM but still no success:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM article

LEFT JOIN article_category
ON article.category_id = article_category.id

WHERE article_category.name_url = 'html'
LIMIT 10`
```

This is what I've came up with so far (I try to write it with only one query just like above):

```php
ArticleCategory::where('name_url', '=', 'html')->with('articles')->get();
```

But it shows an error:

```
Column not found:
1054 Unknown column 'article.article_category_id' in 'where clause'    
(SQL: select * from `article` where `article`.`article_category_id` in (1))
```

My models:

```php
class Article extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'article';

    public function categories() {
         return $this->belongsTo('ArticleCategory', 'category_id');
    }
}

class ArticleCategory extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'article_category';

    public function articles() {
        return $this->hasMany('Article');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your relationship function to use the correct ID.

```
public function articles() {
    return $this->hasMany('Article', 'category_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It expects the column category_id to actually be named article_category_id. It expects this because it is referencing the table artice_catigory, so article_category_id makes sense.

If possible, just rename your column in the table article to article_category_id and everything should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join using eloquent orm as follows

```
Article::leftJoin('article_category', 'article.category_id', '=', 'article_category.id')
            ->select(['*'])->where('article_category.name_url','html')->take(10)->get();
```